# PhantomJS open() too slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm having a problem with web scraping in NodeJS, i want to take some data from the remote webpage but the data is inserted into html from the javascript. I started to use PhantomJS and it works great except one thing that preventing me to finish my job. PhantomJS is working too slow, this snippet of code needs about 14 seconds to execute!?

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://www.halooglasi.com/nekretnine/izdavanje-stanova/novi-beograd---novi-merkator-id19270/5425485514649', function () {
    phantom.exit();
    });
```

with request library who just returns raw data its much faster, a little more than a second so phantomJS is working another 13 seconds or so. It looks like PhantomJS is doing a lot of unnecesary operations which i dont need, i dont need to render pictures videos or anything i just need javascript to execute so i can use cheerio to get the data from html. Can you tell me how to speed up PhantomJS or maybe use some other faster webkit for my needs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several measures you can take to decrease processing time.

1 . Get a more powerful server/computer *(as Mathieu rightly noted)*.

Yes, you could argue this is irrelevant to the question, but in matters of scraping it very much is. On a budget $8 VPS without optimization your initial script ran for `9589ms` which is already a ~30% improvement.

2 . Turn off images load. It will help... a bit. `8160ms` load time.

```
page.settings.loadImages = false;
```

3 .  Analyze the page, find and cancel unnecessary network requests.

Even in a normal browser like Google Chrome the site loads slowly: 129 requests/8.79s load time with AdblockPlus. [There are a lot of requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxHM0.gif) (gif, 1Mb), many if them are for third-party sites like facebook, twitter (to fetch widgets) and to ad sites.

We can cancel them too:

```
block_urls = ['gstatic.com', 'adocean.pl', 'gemius.pl', 'twitter.com', 'facebook.net', 'facebook.com', 'planplus.rs'];

page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request){
    for(url in block_urls) {
        if(requestData.url.indexOf(block_urls[url]) !== -1) {
            request.abort();
            console.log(requestData.url + " aborted");
            return;
        }
    }   
}
```

The load time for me now is just `4393ms` while the page is loaded and usable: [PhantomJS screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3go6.png)

I don't think much more can be done without tinkering with page's code because judging by the page source it is quite script-heavy.

The whole code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require("fs");

// console.time polyfill from https://github.com/callmehiphop/console-time
;(function( console ) {
  var timers;
  if ( !console ) {
    return;
  }
  timers = {};
  console.time = function( name ) {
    if ( name ) {
      timers[ name ] = Date.now();
    }
  };
  console.timeEnd = function( name ) {
    if ( timers[ name ] ) {
      console.log( name + ': ' + (Date.now() - timers[ name ]) + 'ms' );
      delete timers[ name ];
    }
  };
}( window.console ));

console.time("open");

page.settings.loadImages = false;
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36';
page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1280,
  height: 800
};

block_urls = ['gstatic.com', 'adocean.pl', 'gemius.pl', 'twitter.com', 'facebook.net', 'facebook.com', 'planplus.rs'];
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request){
    for(url in block_urls) {
        if(requestData.url.indexOf(block_urls[url]) !== -1) {
            request.abort();
            console.log(requestData.url + " aborted");
            return;
        }
    }            
}

page.open('https://www.halooglasi.com/nekretnine/izdavanje-stanova/novi-beograd---novi-merkator-id19270/5425485514649', function () {
    fs.write("longload.html", page.content, 'w');

    console.timeEnd("open");

    setTimeout(function(){
        page.render('longload.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 3000);

});
```

Comment: I'm interested in your results, please comment on how's this worked out for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot.The advices you gave me speed up the process a lot! There is one more thing that could be useful for someone with the same problem, there is one more method that is useful and that is `page.settings.resourceTimeout`, if you set this to 1000 miliseconds then phantomJS is doing its job for only one second and then finishes, this can be useful although sometimes your content may not be loaded if time is set too low, so its not a very safe solution.Thank you very much for your effort!