# how to get javascript generated content from webpage directly?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, phantomjs

I am currently using selenium with PhantomJS to scrape javascript generated content from a web page. While this does get me the results I am looking for, it is a slow approach as I need to wait for the page to load before scraping. Is there a way to directly run the javascript that generates the content I am looking for? If there is, will it be a faster approach than I am currently using?

Thanks!

Comment: `I need to wait for the page to load before scraping` Could be semantics, but is there any way at all to scrape a page *before* having it (i.e. loading)?

Comment: Is the content actually *generated* by javascript or (more likely) *retrieved* by that javascript from an external source?

Comment: Or do you mean that page generally loads slowly? If yes, then have a look at this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42710420/2715393

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not. I've encountered this problem several times and the only solution I've come up with is to approach the problem the way you are already doing.
Being the content js-generated, the only way to fetch it is to get it from a browser, therefore using selenium with whichever driver you prefer.