# Read content from rendered webpage into nodejs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I would like to read the entire content of a fully rendered webpage into nodejs and do some stuff with the content.

At the moment I am using PhantomJS but it is so unstable. It crashes every 10-20 pages and it leaks memory like crazy. (from 300MB to 2.8GB after just 15 pages)

[image]

Its the same on our Ubuntu server - it runs for 10-20 pages and then crashes.

I can see a lot of other people out there have exact same problem with PhantomJS.

So I wondered... what are the alternatives?

Anyone here knows about how to fix PhamtomJS or knows another simple stable component which can read a rendered webpage and put it into a variable in nodejs?

Any help will be MUCH appreciated - I wasted over 100 hours trying to get PhantomJS to work (new instance for each page, re-using same instance, turning down the speed using timeouts etc etc etc...  no matter what it still leaks and still crashes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past when scraping heavy sites I achieved good results cancelling some of the requests made to 3d party sites, like Google Maps, Facebook and Twitter widgets, ad distributors and such, see [here in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42710420/2715393).

But nowadays I just suggest [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/). It's a native node module, it uses the latest Chromium as a browser and it is being continuously developed by Google engineers. API ideology is based on that of PhantomJS. Usage in node 8+ with async/await provides the most satisfying scraping experience.

Puppeteer is a bit heavier on the hardware though.

Consider the example for getting the page contents:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://angular.io/', {waitUntil : 'networkidle2'});
  const contents = await page.content();
  console.log(contents);
  await browser.close();
});
```

Comment: Great Vaviloff - will try it at once and let you know how it goes.   I got PhantomJS up to 100+ pages before it crashes now - by recreating the browser instance for every page, and setting the page and browser to NULL and then waiting 30 sec for garbage collection to expire the elements.  But....  still crashing.

Comment: MUCH more stable!! but very strange with its waitforFunction etc.. - none of them work on angular rendered pages.